# Snowflake: Equivalent of Oracle USERENV('LANG') in Snowflake

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata, snowflake-schema

Looking for a proper alternative to function ***USERENV('LANG')*** which get the default Language value in Teradata to Snowflake version.

Exp Query:

```
SELECT 
A.EMPID, A.EMP_LANGUAGE
B.EMP_SAL
FROM EMPLOYEE A, 
EMP_SALARY B
WHERE A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID 
AND A.EMP_LANGUAGE = USERENV('LANG');
```

Comment: `show parameters like 'LANGUAGE' in session;` As of today  Snowflake only supports [ja, en]. Please describe what are you trying to achieve instead of performing direct translation

Comment: For that matter, `USERENV()` is legacy Oracle, not Teradata. Equivalent in Teradata might be something like selecting from dbc.SesssionInfoV WHERE SessionNo=SESSION